# $A \oplus B$ a direct sum of $R$-modules. Possible to have a submodule $X$ of $A \oplus B$ s.t. $X \cap A = 0 = X \cap B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A \oplus B$ be a direct sum of left $R$-modules. Is it possible to have a non-zero submodule $X$ of $A \oplus B$ such that $X \cap A = 0 = X \cap B$?

Perhaps not. A submodule of $A \oplus B$ would be of the form $C \oplus D$ with $C \leq A$, $B \leq D$, and both $C$ and $D$ would contain zero so wouldn't $C \oplus \{0\} \subset C \oplus D \cap A$?

Comment: Consider the case where A, B, and R are all the real numbers.

Comment: Hm, still can't think of anything, lol.

Comment: Well, in that case submodules are the same as subspaces. Does $\mathbb{R}^2$ have subspaces that intersect trivially with the coordinate axes?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on $A$ and $B$ (and $R$).

For example, if $R$ is a field and $A,B$ are nonzero $R$-vector spaces, then there are ($1$-dimensional) vector subspaces of $A\oplus B$ not contained in $A$ or $B$.

On the other hand, if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $A=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, then the only nontrivial submodules of $A\oplus B=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ are $A,B$ and $A\oplus B$.

Comment: I realize that containment wouldn't hold, but would the intersection be trivial?